# PostgreSQL INSERT FROM SELECT with additional column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have table `T1` in database `DB1` and table `T2` in database `DB2`, those tables have almost identical sets of columns except column `C_additional` in `T1`, which is not present in `T2`. I need to transfer all the rows from `T2` to `T1`, setting some value of `C_additional` for each row i insert. For example: `T1` and `T2` have only one column `C1` of type `integer` and `T1` also has column `C_additional` of type `text`, so my code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO T1
SELECT 
        C1,
        C_additional='needed_value'
FROM dblink(
    'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=DB2 user=postgres password=postgres', 
    'SELECT * FROM T2')
AS T2_row(C1 integer)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "C_additional" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Hint: There is a column named "C_additional" in table "T1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

How can I do the data transfer using SQL, or should I use PG/SQL?

Comment: Show us t1's and t2's definitions.

Comment: `C_additional='needed_value'` is a boolean expression that evaluates if the column name `C_additional` equals the constant `'needed_value'`. If you want a column alias use one: `'needed_value' as c_additional`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the target columns with parenthesis before the `select` clause:

```
INSERT INTO T1
(c1, c_additional) -- here
SELECT 
        C1,
        'needed_value' -- just select a constant here
FROM dblink(
    'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=DB2 user=postgres password=postgres', 
    'SELECT * FROM T2')
AS T2_row(C1 integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
INSERT INTO T1
SELECT 
        C1,
        'needed_value'
FROM dblink(
    'hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=DB2 user=postgres password=postgres', 
    'SELECT * FROM T2')
AS T2_row(C1 integer)
```